# Foreign Key Encryption W/ Jasypt and GORM ORM

Tags: grails, encryption, grails-orm, jasypt

I actually work on a project who deals with sensible data on my database, so i need to encrypt them.

My technical environment is like this :

- Web Framework : Grails (v2.4.4)
- ORM : GORM (based on Hibernate 4)
- Encryption library : Jasypt (v1.3.1)

In all data I have to encrypt, I can figure out 2 cases :

1. Simple attribute (eg. forename, lastname, etc.). I already know how to deal with this ( Hibernate type transformation : http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html ). So no problem for this one.
2. Link between two objects (eg. Person object and Job object). I want to break the link between these two tables on the database, therefore it will be impossible to find the link between Person and  Job with a "where" request on the DB. This is my actual problem.

Here is a sample example of code to enlight case #2 :

ParentClass.groovy :

```
class ParentClass extends …  implements ...{

    String id

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'my.package.CustomGeneratorUtils'

    }   
}
```

ChildClass.groovy :

```
class ChildClass extends ... implements ...{

    static belongsTo = [parentClass : ParentClass]

    ...   

    static mapping = {

        parentClass column: 'parentClass_id', insertable: false, updateable: false

        parentClass type: GormEncryptedStringType

    }

    ...

}
```

Here is a list of elements regarding my issue :

- GORM automatically  creates tables on the DB corresponding to business objects
- GORM automatically  creates a parentClass_id column into the ChildClass table in order to make the link
- I do have a ParentClass with a technical primary key, with a 0..n relation with ChildClass
- I need to go through String typed id because the encrypted value is an alphanumeric value. That's why I use a custom id generator which allow me to build a String typed id with a classic sequence in the DB.
- I'd like to keep the ParentClass Id in clear, but to encrypt the foreign key of the ChildClass referencing the parentClass Table.

Thank's for your help !

Comment: did you get your answer here? i'm interested in the second part (breaking the link by encrypting the foreign key) thanks in advance